# Python how to access dataframes inside dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Say I am creating data-frames from different csv files.
I wrote a function to read the files into DF and return them as a dictionary. Now i cannot access them separately.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

path = ("/folder")


def readDatafromFile(path):
    store_data = {}
    a = 0
    path = (path + "/data")
    os.chdir(path)
    filenames = glob.glob("*.txt")
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.__contains__("_Sale") == 1:
            Salesource = path + "/" + filename
            store_data[1] = pd.read_csv(Salesource, sep=',', header=None)
        elif filename.__contains__("_Emplo") == 1:
            Empsource = path + "/" + filename
            store_data[2] = pd.read_csv(Empsource, sep=',', header=None)
        elif filename.__contains__("_Prod") == 1:
            Prodsource = path + "/" + filename
            store_data[3] = pd.read_csv(Prodsource, sep=',', header=None)
        elif filename.__contains__("_Resou") == 1:
            Ressource = path + "/" + filename
            store_data[4] = pd.read_csv(Ressource, sep=',', header=None)

            a = a + 1
    return (store_data)
    print(a)

shop = readDatafromFile(path)
```

How to access shop sales for example or shop emp?

Comment: You are overwriting the values of `store_data` in every loop. You want to have a list and append the intermediate results in each loop execution.

Comment: no not really. i can access all the values if i just print shop but i cannot access them separately.

Comment: uphill is correct. What do you mean you can access all the values if you print `shop`? That object holds the data from `store_data`, which is what your function returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need append each `DataFrame` to list and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
def readDatafromFile(path):
    sales, emp, prod, res = [], [], [], []
    path = (path + "/data")
    os.chdir(path)
    filenames = glob.glob("*.txt")
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.__contains__("_Sale") == 1:
            Salesource = path + "/" + filename
            sales.append(pd.read_csv(Salesource, sep=',', header=None))
        elif filename.__contains__("_Emplo") == 1:
            Empsource = path + "/" + filename
            emp.append(pd.read_csv(Empsource, sep=',', header=None))
        elif filename.__contains__("_Prod") == 1:
            Prodsource = path + "/" + filename
            prod.append(pd.read_csv(Prodsource, sep=',', header=None))
        elif filename.__contains__("_Resou") == 1:
            Ressource = path + "/" + filename
            res.append(pd.read_csv(Ressource, sep=',', header=None))

    salesdf = pd.concat(sales, ignore_index=True)
    empdf = pd.concat(emp, ignore_index=True)
    proddf = pd.concat(prod, ignore_index=True)
    resdf = pd.concat(res, ignore_index=True)

    store_data = {'sales':salesdf, 'emp':empdf,'prod':proddf, 'res':resdf}
    return (store_data)

shop = readDatafromFile(path)

print (shop['sales'])
```

EDIT:

Solution with `defaultdict`, thank you [`Reti43`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46708345/python-how-to-access-dataframes-inside-dictionary#comment80364012_46708757) for idea.

```
def readDatafromFile(path):

    from collections import defaultdict
    store_data = defaultdict(list)

    path = (path + "/data")
    os.chdir(path)
    filenames = glob.glob("*.txt")
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.__contains__("_Sale") == 1:
            Salesource = path + "/" + filename
            store_data['sales'].append(pd.read_csv(Salesource, sep=',', header=None))
        elif filename.__contains__("_Emplo") == 1:
            Empsource = path + "/" + filename
            store_data['emp'].append(pd.read_csv(Empsource, sep=',', header=None))
        elif filename.__contains__("_Prod") == 1:
            Prodsource = path + "/" + filename
            store_data['prod'].append(pd.read_csv(Prodsource, sep=',', header=None))
        elif filename.__contains__("_Resou") == 1:
            Ressource = path + "/" + filename
            store_data['res'].append(pd.read_csv(Ressource, sep=',', header=None))

    store_data['sales'] = pd.concat(store_data['sales'], ignore_index=True)
    store_data['emp'] = pd.concat(store_data['emp'], ignore_index=True)
    store_data['prod'] = pd.concat(store_data['prod'], ignore_index=True)
    store_data['res'] = pd.concat(store_data['res'], ignore_index=True)

    return (store_data)
```

Comment: Instead of creating four explicit lists, you can use a `collections.defaultdict(list)` object.

Comment: @Reti43 - Really thank you for your comment, I implement it to solution.

Answer (score 0):

## As is

You can access your dataframes in your original code, you just need to use the keys you actually put in the dictionary:

```
In [6]: shop.keys()
Out[6]: dict_keys([2, 3, 4, 1])
```

So, you would use `shop[1]` to get the "sales" dataframe out based on your code.

## Simplified

Probably, though you're really looking for meaningful keys. In that case, you could just use the file names. In fact, you could make this code completely general if you wanted:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

path = ("/folder")


def readDatafromFile(path):
    store_data = {}
    a = 0
    path = (path + "/data")
    os.chdir(path)
    filenames = glob.glob("*.txt")
    for filename in filenames:
        store_data[filename] = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',', header=None)
        a = a + 1
    return (store_data)
    print(a)

shop = readDatafromFile(path)
```

Notice, that this will include all the *.txt files and use their exact filenames. So, if you want, you could start with a dictionary of keys and filename fragments: `{'employees' : '_Emp`, ...}` and then loop over that dictionary to create a new one on the same keys, but the with the contents of each file as the value.

Answer (score 0):

That method looks a bit overcomplicated IMHO. There might be good reason for creating these *source* objects. But since they are all basically the same, you can achieve the same functionality with less code:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

path = ("/folder")


def readDatafromFile(path):
    store_data = {}
    a = 0
    path = (path + "/data")
    os.chdir(path)
    filenames = glob.glob("*.txt")

    valid_file_names = [
        "_Sale",
        "_Emplo",
        "_Prod",
        "_Resou"
    ]

    for filename in filenames:
        if any(val in filename for val in valid_file_names):
            source_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
            # remove .txt
            filename = filename[:-4]
            store_data[filename] = pd.read_csv(source_path, sep=',', header=None)
            a = a + 1

    print(a)
    return store_data

shop = readDatafromFile(path)
```

You can then access the dataframe by using `shop[filename]` (filename without *.txt*).